# VBA Macro: Error 5113

Tags: vba, memory, runtime-error

I'm having a trouble that randomly appears, once a week/2 weeks. It happens with this code:

```
Sub ImagenesToNormal()
'Procedimiento para pasar las imagenes a estilo de texto normal
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1

        ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).Select
        Selection.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
        Selection.Range.InsertAfter Chr(13)

    Next i
End Sub
```

For example, the last time, document had 39 pictures(this was an OCR Abbyy-ed document). If I execute this, error appears, but memory isn't even at half of 4gb total(including OS and more crap running). Even CPU is only at 42%, but I get this error. If I run it step by step, error doesn't happen. And even if I reboot, problem wont happen anymore.

I've searched around the web and I don't find any solution/cause.

Answer (score 1):

In those rare instances when you get the error, does the script do anything at all to the document and then stops halfway, or does it fail to start altogether?

One thing I can think of is that occasionally, when you execute the script, a document that is active is not the one you intend to apply changes to, hence the error. And later when you rerun in, the document somehow is made active. If your script fails to start, that’s probably the reason.

in reply to yor comment:
When the error happens, how many documents did you have open at that time? Is the error replicable? In other words, if you run the script again (not step-by-step and without activating the target document) do you get the same error?
I would start with something like:

```
Dim mydoc As Document 
Set mydoc = Application.Documents("mydocname.docx")

For i = mydoc.InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1

        mydoc.InlineShapes(i).Select
        Selection.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Style = mydoc.Styles("Normal")
        Selection.Range.InsertAfter Chr(13)

Next i
```

In reply to your *too quick* comment:

From what you've told me so far, I thing that one of the inline shapes in your document, when selected, doesn't support *ClearFormatting* method. Inline shapes come in different types (see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221989%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for details, at the end they list all the types). So this is what happens: your script reformats inline shapes one-by-one till it stumbles on one that can't be CelarFormatted, that it stops and reports an error. When you continue in debug mode, you basically tell it to 'step over' the 'bad' object. All remaining inline shapes are fine and your script finishes the rest of the document. 
To solve the problem you need to nail down that inline shape and see what's so spacial about it. Then you can add an *If - Then* condition to your script so it avoid such inline shapes.

Comment: I've tried to run it on another PC(with half the RAM as mine) and it works OK with the same document and action :S. Therefore, with that procedure RAM usage by Word only reaches about 80 MB :S:S:S

ad told you, if I launch it, it crashes while doing "Selection.clearformatting", but if I run it step by step, it doesn't crash

Comment: Tried and it worked. Indeed the problem was a missed pointer to the document.

Comment: Too quick...it happens again. It always happens in `Selection.ClearFormatting` and don't know why. And if I use debug after getting error, it continues without problem.

Comment: I've added another suggestion.

Comment: As told before, it happens randomly and only ni my PC. If i run this macro on this document in other PC, it doesn't give an error. It may be some kind of problem with user profile.

Comment: are office versions same? what office do you use, and what's on the other PC?